# Database Generation (copy data on different tabs)

Tags: google-sheets

I'm creating a spreadsheet on google with the goal of automating the storage and management of data. To do this, people fill in the data in an "Entries" tab and I need to develop a script that launches this data into the "DB" database.

Image1

In this image it shows the flap people fill in. My idea is that with a button at the end of the fill the information will be sent to the database as shown below:

Image2

I put the colors referring to the columns that should be copied in "Entries" and pasted in "BD"

I tried to create the following script:

```
function moveValuesOnly() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getRange('Entradas!B9:J29);
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName('BD');
  var lastFilledRowInColumnA = getLastPopulatedRow(destSheet.getRange('A:A').getValues());
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(lastFilledRowInColumnA+1,1);
  source.copyTo(destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
  source.clear();
```

};

But, I can not do the copying and pasting of information.

Can you help me please. I've been trying for over two months and I can not seem to sort it out.

Follow the link to the spreadsheet template: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BuLBU2qKB8ZNMi_wVvTHwW6MyODDTKPoP5Imn1r1L7Q/edit?usp=sharing

Google-Sheets

```
function moveValuesOnly() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getRange('Entradas!B9:J29');
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName('BD');
  var lastFilledRowInColumnA = getLastPopulatedRow(destSheet.getRange('A:A').getValues());
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(lastFilledRowInColumnA+1,1);
  source.copyTo(destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
  source.clear();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're missing two things:

First, it looks like you used [this site](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/rgjWgtwKarA/q83z9_gAAwAJ) as a template for your code (which is perfectly fine). However, you forgot to copy over the function `getLastPopulatedRow`.

Second, you needed to attach your image to your script. As a test, I referenced [these instructions](http://googleappscripting.com/google-spreadsheet-button/) on how to create a button on your sheet connected to your macro.

After taking these steps, it looks like your code works.

Comment: The code worked, but now the new information I put in the input is going over the data I've entered before. Can you help me with this issue?